# SwiftUI push view on navigation stack when optional object is not nil

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my app, I have a `CheckoutView` that collects the user's payment information and charges their order to their credit card. Within the `CheckoutViewModel`, I have an optional property `@Published var order: Order?` which is set once the payment is successful and we receive a response from our payment processor.

My `CheckoutView` is presented modally in a `NavigationView`. When we receive a successful payment response, I want to push another view onto the navigation stack to indicate to the user that their payment went through.

In my `CheckoutView`, I have the following code:

```
struct CheckoutView: View {

  var body: some View { 
    ...
    if let order = viewModel.order {
      let orderStatusView = OrderStatusView(viewModel: OrderStatusViewModel(order: order))
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
      
      NavigationLink(
        destination: orderStatusView,
        isActive: .constant(true)
      ) { EmptyView }
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect this to push the `OrderStatusView` onto the navigation stack once the `order` property is set, however the opposite happens and the modally presented `NavigationView` gets dismissed instead.

I understand I can accomplish this using a `@State var` and have done so in other places in my app, however in this case the view to be presented requires an `Order` object to render its view and I'd rather not have to make the dependency optional.

Has anyone had any success handling this kind of situation in SwiftUI?

Comment: Add an `orderProcessed: Bool` to your `Order` object, instantiate with default values and remove the optional. Then use that condition to go forward as you're expecting.